# UTF8 + PHP + MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8

Как исправить код чтобы вместо вопросительных знаков показывало литовские буквы?

> Nu k�, sumas�iau patestuoti, �i�r�sim kaip �ia bus! - показывает.
>   Nu ką, sumasčiau patestuoti, pažiūrėsim kaip čia bus! - должно показывать.
>   Nu kà, sumasèiau patestuoti, þiûrësim kaip èia bus! - в базе данных.

**MySQL connection collation: utf8_general_ci

MySQL Row Collation: utf8_general_ci**

В .php файле:

```
<META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

mysql_query("DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8");
mysql_query("COLLATE utf8_lithuanian_ci");
mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");
```

не помогло

---

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

не помогло.

Из google ничего не помогло.

Comment: 1. команду *set names utf8* вы передаёте **до** подключения к базе данных или **после**? 2. уточните, пожалуйста: у вас действительно в базе данных хранится не то, что должно отображаться?

Comment: 1. set names после подключения. 2. в базе данных храниться вроде бы та информация которая нужна. Информация используется для игрового сервера. В таком виде записывает, а извлекает в правильном (с литовскими символами).

Comment: Я с литовскими буквами не работал, но и не имел проблем с этим. Попробуйте файл конфигурации апача и добавьте туда строчку AddDefaultCharset UTF-8 (htaccess), мне обычно помогает заголовок header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8'); я его поверх выводов ставлю, и не использовал такую вещь <META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />, как с mysql я использую pdo и подключаюсь к нему таким методом if(EncodingBoolean)$options = array( PDO:: MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES '.EncodingMysql);
    $this->con = new PDO(тддд, $options);

Comment: есть подозрение, что в базе данных строки хранятся не в кодировке *utf8*, а в какой-то однобайтовой кодировке. может быть, что-то вроде [ISO 8859-4 (Latin-4)](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8859).

Comment: @Денис Котляров, файл конфигурации апача это какой файл?

Comment: @alexander barakin, возможно, но как тогда это исправить?

Comment: @ES., прежде, чем исправлять, надо определить, что же на самом деле хранится в базе данных. для начала посмотрите, что по поводу кодировок говорят такие запросы: `show create database имя_вашей_базы_данных;` и `show create table та_самая_таблица_со_строками;`

Comment: @alexander barakin, CREATE DATABASE `johurt` /*!40100 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 */ , CREATE TABLE `stw` (
`ID` int(5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`Vardas` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '­',
`IP` varchar(15) NOT NULL DEFAULT '­',
`Pranesimas` varchar(128) NOT NULL DEFAULT '­',
`Data` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '­',
PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

Comment: предположим, что всё так и есть. тогда посмотрите, что именно приходит: 1. по поводу кодировок в *http*-заголовках от сервера, 2. непосредственно в *html*-тексте страницы. // как это сделать из-под *ms/windows* — я, увы, подсказать не смогу, так как мало знаком с этой системой.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Перепробовал разные варианты кодировок/декодировок, ничего не получилось, так как почему то сам игровой сервер не корректно записывает информацию в БД. Решил проблему так:

```html
$from = array("À", "È", "Æ", "Ë", "Á", "Ð", "Ø", "Û", "Þ", "à", "è", "æ", "ë", "á", "ð", "ø", "û", "þ");
$to = array("Ą", "Č", "Ę", "Ė", "Į", "Š", "Ų", "Ū", "Ž", "ą", "č", "ę", "ė", "į", "š", "ų", "ū", "ž");
$ePranesimas = str_replace($from, $to, $buss['Pranesimas']);
```

Также из всего оставил лишь:

```html
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
mysql_set_charset("utf8");
```

Спасибо что не прошли мимо и попытались помочь.

Answer (score 0):

Именно с литовскими буквами не работал, но работал с другими буквами, относящимися к UTF-8. При создании базы данных в MySQL collation выбирал "utf8_general_ci". В PHP попробуй прописать этот код:

```
<?php
echo '<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /> ';
$host= "localhost";
$user= "root";
$pass= "";

$connect= mysql_connect($host,$user,$pass);
if (!$connect)  {
 die ("Baglanyp bolanok!");
}
$db="databasename";

mysql_query("SET character_set_results=utf8", $connect);
mb_language('uni');
mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');
mysql_select_db($db, $connect);

mysql_query("set names 'utf8'",$connect);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

На Вашем месте я бы уже не использовал устаревший `mysql_*`, а использовал `mysqli_*` или `PDO`

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('127.0.0.1', 'root', '1111', 'db_name');
$mysqli->set_charset('utf8');
```

А кодировку базы и таблиц я бы изменил на `utf8_unicode_ci`

[Вот почему](http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) стоит переходить на новые библиотеки

Comment: Этот не относящийся к вопросу комментарий не является ответом.

Comment: @Ипатьев, Ваш комментарий не несет никакой информации, которая могла бы помочь вопросу. У меня ответ по сути. Проблема с кодировкой. Я указал на те вещи, которые можно изменить, чтобы получить желательный результат.