# Почему в таблице mysql текст на русском, а при выводе в скрипте одни "?"

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Возникла проблема: в базе данных текст на русском(кодировка utf-8, сравнение utf-8 general ci), но при отправлении сообщения в телеграмм текст превращается в знаки вопроса(сколько букв в стоке, столько символов вопроса)
[image: Одни знаки вопроса]

А вот строка в бд:
[image: запись из базы данных]

Вот код:

```
$searchItem = $DBH->prepare('SELECT * FROM items WHERE id = :id'); //Готовим запрос
    $searchItem->bindParam(':id', $id);//биндим id
    $searchItem->execute();//Отправляем запрос
    $item = $searchItem->fetch();//Получаем результат
    Inquiry::send($bot, 'sendMessage', [
        'chat_id' => $userId,
        'text' => 'Вы получили новый предмет: '.$item['name']//Получаем нужную строку, которая вместо русского текста выводит "?"
    ]);
```

А вот метод send:

```
        public static function send($bot , $method, $data) {

    $canSended = [
               'sendmessage',
               'sendaudio',
               'sendphoto',
               'senddocument',
               'sendanimation',
               'sendpoll',
               'sendvenue',
               'editmessagetext',
               'editmessagecaption',
               'editmessagemedia',
               'editmessagereplymarkup',
               'getuserprofilephotos', 
               'getfile',
               'getchat',
               'getchatmember',
               'getchatmemberscount',
               'getme',
               'sendchataction',
               'sendInvoice'
    ];

    $url = 'https://api.telegram.org/bot'.$bot->getToken().'/'.$method.'?';

    $finded = false;

    for($i = 0;$i < count($canSended);$i++){
        if(strcasecmp($method,$canSended[$i]) == 0){
            $finded = true;
        }
    }

    if($finded == false){
        return new \Error('Unknown telegram method');
    }

    foreach($data as $key=>$value) {
        switch($key) {
            case 'reply_markup':
                $data['reply_markup'] = json_encode($value, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
                break;
        }
    }

    self::query($url, $data);
}
```

query:

```
protected static function query($url, $postFields, $mode = false) {
    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postFields);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type:multipart/form-data"));

    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    switch ($mode) {
        case 'get':
            return $data;
            break;

        default:
            return true;
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Смотрите соответствие кодировки БД и кодировки файла скрипта.

Comment: Ваш вопрос очередной дубль, очень популярный, разжеванный до самых мелочей, воспользуйтесь поиском по ruSO или вообще по интернету, и за пару минут найдете прям именно ваш случай, вот как пример: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [UTF8 + PHP + MySQL](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/452532/utf8-php-mysql)

Answer (score 1):

А вот и ответ:
$DBH = new PDO('mysql:host=;charset=utf8;dbname=', '', '');
Спасибо конечно, но мой вопрос был про PDO, но никак не про mysqli

Comment: А какая разница? PDO\MySQLi - и то и то легко находится на этом сайте. Проблему вам сразу укзали - кодировки =)

Answer (score -1):

Установить в php на всякий случай.
`mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");`

И установить туже кодировку получения данных

```
mysqli_query($conn, "SET NAMES 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci'");
mysqli_query($conn, "SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8'");
```

Comment: Ваш ответ может стать вредным(а может и полезным) для автора, описанный случай - не единственное место проблем с кодировкой, имхо - на такие вопросы отвечать не стоит, лучше отправить в поиск, или привести ссылки на ответы которые уже опубликованы, тем более их на данном сайте великое множество, на любой вкус и цвет =)
и да, вторая комманда - бесполезна после первой =0 (SET CHARACTER)